# QLikView calculated dimension with aggregation w.r.t. other dimension in pivot-table

Tags: excel, algorithm, aggregate-functions, pivot-table, qlikview

In a pivot table, I have one calculated dimension with complex expression:

```
pick(1+match(IF([Corporate Account]='OTHER','[Sales Account]', 
'[Corporate Account]'),...,...,...),...,...,...,...)
```

In another dimension, I want to sum revenu with respect to this first dimension. More precisely, I want to have value for this new calculated dimension be 'A' or 'B' depending on the total revenue with respect to the first field.

So far, I came up with

```
=AGGR( IF(Sum(Revenue)>10,'A','B'),
$(=pick(1+match(IF([Corporate Account]='OTHER','[Sales Account]', 
'[Corporate Account]'),...,...,...),...,...,...,...)))
```

and this is not correct (for all rows, output is Null()).

Would you have an idea of what is the right syntax ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full dimension expression it is not that easy to diagnose the issue, however, I tried to recreate your expression:

```
=aggr(if(sum(Revenue)>10,'A','B'),
$(=pick(match(IF([Corporate Account]='OTHER','[Sales Account]', '[Corporate Account]'),
'[Corporate Account]', '[Sales Account]'),'[Sales Account]', '[Corporate Account]')))
```

I noticed that if I put the dimensions in the `pick()` entries in quotes then the expression is evaluated fine since `pick()` would return a quoted value, e.g. `'[Sales Account]'` which is then evaluated by `$()` to `[Sales Account]` and so becomes a "real" dimension which `aggr()` can use as an aggregation dimension.

If this doesn't work, please could you add your full expression?